# Neural Network from scratch using Python

Tags: python, neural-network

I am trying to implement a NN from scratch in Python. It has 2 layers: input layer –
output layer. The input layer will have 4 neurons and the output layer will have only a
single node (+biases). I have the following code but I get the error message: ValueError: shapes (4,2) and (4,1) not aligned: 2 (dim 1) != 4 (dim 0). Can someone help me?

```
import numpy as np

# Step 1: Define input and output data
X = np.array([[0, 0, 1, 1], [0, 1, 0, 1]])
y = np.array([[0, 1, 0, 1]])

# Step 2: Define the number of input neurons, hidden neurons, and output neurons
input_neurons = 4
output_neurons = 1

# Step 3: Define the weights and biases for the network
weights = np.random.rand(input_neurons, output_neurons)
biases = np.random.rand(output_neurons, 1)

# Step 4: Define the sigmoid activation function
def sigmoid(x):
    return 1 / (1 + np.exp(-x))

# Step 5: Define the derivative of the sigmoid function
def sigmoid_derivative(x):
    return sigmoid(x) * (1 - sigmoid(x))

# Step 6: Define the forward propagation function
def forward_propagation(X, weights, biases):
    output = sigmoid(np.dot(X.T, weights) + biases)
    return output

# Step 7: Define the backward propagation function
def backward_propagation(X, y, output, weights, biases):
    error = output - y
    derivative = sigmoid_derivative(output)
    delta = error * derivative
    weights_derivative = np.dot(X, delta.T)
    biases_derivative = np.sum(delta, axis=1, keepdims=True)
    return delta, weights_derivative, biases_derivative

# Step 8: Define the train function
def train(X, y, weights, biases, epochs, learning_rate):
    for i in range(epochs):
        output = forward_propagation(X, weights, biases)
        delta, weights_derivative, biases_derivative = backward_propagation(X, y, output, weights, biases)
        weights -= learning_rate * weights_derivative
        biases -= learning_rate * biases_derivative
        error = np.mean(np.abs(delta))
        print("Epoch ", i, " error: ", error)

# Step 9: Train the network
epochs = 5000
learning_rate = 0.1
train(X, y, weights, biases, epochs, learning_rate)
```

Comment: The error is happening when you try to do `np.dot(X.T, weights)` because you can't dot-product a 4x2 matrix (`X.T`) with a 4x1 matrix (`weights`). You should investigate why you have the wrong matrix dimensions at this step.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an output layer with one neuron, so your output should be of one dimension.
You're assuming that the output has 4 dims:

```py
y = np.array([[0, 1, 0, 1]])
```

Since you are giving two inputs (a pair of 4 dim inputs) like this,

```py
X = np.array([[0, 0, 1, 1], [0, 1, 0, 1]])
```

You need also give two outputs (in one dim), for example like this:

```py
y = np.array([[0],[1]])
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I have changed the initialisation of y but this results in the same error

Comment: So basically the error is from the `output = sigmoid(np.dot(X.T, weights) + biases)` , because here `X.T` is of shape of (4,2) and `weights` is of shape of (4,1). @StetcoOana

Comment: how can I change the "weights" to be shaped (4,2), or how can I fix this problem overall?

Comment: remove `.T` from `X.T` @StetcoOana

Comment: still has the same error...I will try a new approach